# How important is pitch perception ability in musical creativity?

Tags: composition, ear-training, relative-pitch

There are a few online tests that give you a measure of your pitch perception ability (such as the [jake mandell tone deaf test](http://jakemandell.com/tonedeaf/)). I took the test and I scored a 67% in my first attempt and 77% in my second attempt.

These are not great results and some of my friends with no musical training have scored above 80% easily. I assume this means that I have relatively bad pitch perception ability or memory.

I have two questions.

1. Is the pitch perception ability a necessity to compose music?
2. When I play the piano, I can easily put into notes what I hear in my mind. Then why is a scientific test telling me otherwise?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. No, it's absolutely not necessarily.  It can certainly be helpful in a number of ways, but experimentation and perseverance can get you far.  One example of an accomplished tone-deaf composer is [Robert Fripp](http://www.fripp.com/he-was-left-handed-tone-deaf-and-had-no-sense-of-rhythm/).  It's not necessary to know exactly what note you're hearing to know that it sounds good!
2. That test is *hard*.  As the page says, "excellent musicians rarely score above 80%".  My main problem when taking it myself was remembering the first phrase while hearing the second.  I really don't think that's a good test for tone-deafness at all, more of a specific type of memory test, and it's certainly not very similar to playing something you "hear" mentally.

   Tone deaf people can usually still tell when things are *different*, just not *how*.  This means they have trouble specifically identifying intervals or even whether notes are higher or lower than others; essentially, they lack relative pitch.

Answer (score 2):

I would have thought "pitch perception" (Which is another test on the site) is more of a definition of "tone deafness" than listening to phrases and remembering them. I think it would be hard to compose without having at least this to a decent level.

If its of any consolation I did extremely bad on the test last year and exceptionally well on the test today. Since last year I have been forcing myself to stop writing music and improve my skills by learning songs. I have reduced time spent on my creativity and increased my memory, focus and ability to remember faster phrases than I could before.

Is a good score on the Jake Mandell pitch perception test indicative of creative writing? my answer would be definitely not. Because in my case the opposite seems to apply.